# Best way to catch Zend_DB exceptions in already existing code?

Tags: php, zend-framework, exception, zend-db

I need to catch Zend_DB exceptions at all places in existing code. What would be the best way and place to do it?

One tedious way I think is to wrap all query code in try catch block but there are so many queries in multiple files. So looking for better and alternate option.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `One tedious way I think is to wrap all query code in try catch block` - tedious it may be, but you ask what the "best" way to do it is, and that is the best way. The original author of the code should have done this when they wrote it, if they didn't you will have to do it now.

Comment: Catch and then do what? If nothing complicated (like just logging and displaying a simple error page), then you could try-catch-wrap the call to `Zend_Application::run()` in `index.php` ;)

Comment: http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-components-13/databases-20/reporting-sql-errors-zend_db-105.html  seems interesting

Comment: what's important to remember here is that exceptions propagate from the inside-out. meaning: suppose you have a `update($entity)` method and it has an error X, it'll throw an exception from the repository (or manager or model, wherever you call it from) in which the query is being made, that propagates to your service layer (where you called the update method, lets say) then that will go to your controller, and to your view. you should think about where you need to do something different if an error ocurrs, and catch and control the exception there

Answer (score 0):

To me, the key is @bububaba's comment to your question: Catch and do what?

The easiest thing to do - so you don't have to dig into db/mapper/model/repository/service controller code - is to just modify your `ErrorController` to "do something different" when the exception is a `Zend_Db_Exception`.

But that's really top-level stuff, the last gasp chance to catch the priceless Ming vase before it hits the floor and shatters into a million pieces, probably so far away from the thrown error that you are missing out on more meaningful ways of handling the error. In general, the closer you are to the throw, the better is your knowledge of the context in which that throw occurred, which then informs/guides the best way to handle it (ex: let it bubble up to the top, catch/rethrow, catch/eat, etc.). In that sense, there is probably real benefit in wrapping up smaller chunks into try/catch blocks.

Just thinking out loud. YMMV.